# Error 405 Method Not Allowed, redirect(url_for('index'))

Tags: flask, http-status-code-405

I'm currently using pythonanywhere for a school project. Below is a piece of the code I'm having problems with.

```
#When at www.example.com/ load "log_in.html" file
@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def index():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("log_in.html")

#When at www.example.com/create_account/
@app.route("/create_account", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def create_account():
   if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("create_account.html", username = username, password = password)

return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

I what intent is for the user to click a button and submit their details to create an account. After the data is recorded, they are redirected back to the log in page which is under 'index'.

Upon testing out the code, everything worked up until the redirecting part which gave me an Error 405, Method not allowed.

The site is at http://fishypower.pythonanywhere.com/create_account
Clicking on the 'create account' button will give the Error 405

Below is the code for http://fishypower.pythonanywhere.com/create_account

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ElderMinder: Create Account</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form action="." method="POST">
                <center><textarea name="username" placeholder="Enter your username"></textarea></center>
                <div></div>
                <center><textarea name="password" placeholder="Enter your password"></textarea></center>
                <div></div>
                <center><input type="submit" value="Create Account"></center>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `<form action="." method="POST">`.  Why did you decide to use a period as the action target?

The action should either be blank, or just leave it out to submit to it's current url or `<form action="{{ url_for('create_account') }}" method="post">` to be explicit.

So, in short, you're getting the error because your form submission is going to `/` and that view only accepts GET requests.

Comment: The above is exactly correct, but just to expand on it a bit: if you're on the page "http://fishypower.pythonanywhere.com/create_account", then `action="."` will submit to "http://fishypower.pythonanywhere.com/".   But if you're on the page "http://fishypower.pythonanywhere.com/create_account/" (note the trailing slash) then `action="."` will submit to "http://fishypower.pythonanywhere.com/create_account/"   The "." means the same as it does in a Unix file path -- the current "directory".

Comment: Thank you for the help. As I've only started recently, my coding is still largely editting samples to suit my need. I intent to have the data sent to a database for storage. Do I have to do anything to the code for this?